# From picture units to real world units

Tags: c#, .net

I need an optimal solution with a program I am working on. The program should take an image(black and white only) with some single black lined objects, like star, circle, rectangle and etc. After, a program should find a location of each black point on it and will track it. By this I according to those location I will make some computations to make my stepper mottor move accordingly. Imagine that there is marker and white board, and I want the picture on my pc to be drawn on whiteboard, by specifying the size .

I don't know, maybe there are some other ways beside the image, and what units is better, pixel based or ....?need some suggestions and recomendations.
 Appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With printing, scanning and monitors, there is the term DPI (Dot-Per-Inch), this is what you need to inspect to determine the real world size of an image.  Compare the DPI of the device, by the number of pixels in your image.

Note, DPI is represented in dots per SQUARE inch.

Comment: That is informative, I will read through this. the term dpi was important for me thanks.

Comment: Uhm, no, it's not per square inch. At least I think monitors with 96 dpi have more than 4 pixels per cm ...

Comment: JOey: I think you're right, it's not per square inch but per inch, According to wiki

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do that with C# , but you can OpenCV and it wrapper for c#   Emgu, you can read the image that you have and convert it to YCbCr color model and, you can you the  contours function or minmaxloc function .